# mapping using kinect only

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Can i build my map using kinect only ?

regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55328/mapping-using-kinect-only/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM) shows building 2D occupancy grid map using kinect and turtlebot as robot base. If ur looking for 3d maps then look for RGBD slam using kinect.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0